# Docker container has no TMPDIR environmental variable

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm running a Node app on node:6.3-wheezy. I noticed that `os.tmpdir()` returns the path to the project directory, which is probably just `PWD`. When I run `env` in the container, I see that there is no `TMPDIR` environmental variable. Why is this? I'd like the system to establish it's own temp directory rather than setting it myself.

Comment: With a container, if you don't define it, it doesn't exist. You should manually set this variable if you need it. This can be done in compose, a Dockerfile, or in your run command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `TMPDIR` has not been set in the container environment.

The only [environment variables docker will set](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/env-environment-variables) are

- `HOME`     - Set based on the value of `USER`
- `HOSTNAME` - The hostname associated with the container
- `PATH`     - Includes common directories, such as :
  `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`
- `TERM`     - `xterm` if the container is allocated a pseudo-TTY (interactive input)

Anything else is image specific and up to you.

You can set them via an [`ENV` step in a Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/env) if needed or on the command line with `--env TMDIR=x`